# Independent Contractor

Tags: income-tax, canada, contractor

I am an employee and fall within the first tax income bracket in Nova Scotia. I have recently taken up a contract job as an independent contractor that pays about $150 to $200 per month. I want to know how much tax i will pay on this income as an independent contractor making about $2,400 in a year in Nova Scotia.

Thanks

Comment: Pretend your normal job raised your wage by CAD2400.  Would that bump you into the next tax bracket?  If so, withhold some money yourself every paycheck.  Even if you stay in the same bracket, there might be other taxes which are withheld from your current pay which you should self-withhold from the contract wages.